# Configure WAMP server to send email

Tags: php, wamp, phpmailer

Is there a way  that I can configure the [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for PHP to enable the `mail()` function?

Comment: different ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830673/wamp-xamp-send-mail-using-smtp-localhost

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Configuring a working email client from localhost is quite a chore, I have spent hours of frustration attempting it. I'm sure someone more experienced may be able to help, or they may perhaps agree with me.

If you just want to test, here is a great tool for testing mail locally, that requires almost no configuration:

http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: Works with wamp with no config watsoever. Just open the .eml with windows live mail (no config needed).

Comment: Working on Win7, working with WAMP just after install

Comment: If (like me) you came to this great solution after tweaking php.ini, remember the default config:

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

Comment: My php.ini file is set up correctly, but I get no e-mails in the specified folder after setting up this tool on win 8.1. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: This is a great solution, but I'm having trouble with performance. It seems the more content a mail contains, the slower it will be to get to me. Does anyone have a solution, could it just be my aging computer?

Comment: Works on windows 8.1 too, installed this for testing mails using wamp server

Comment: Wow useful, installed with no configuration in 2 minutes, refreshed my page, and boom the error message disappeared and received the email on my desktop.

Comment: This is a wonderful tool and it helps dev a lot.     We have found a problem with it in that it does NOT handle the case where "." is present in column zero of a logical record sent to SMTP.  Zend formats our email and it correctly adds a "dot" to the string when the logical start of the line (every 75th character I think) is already a "dot".  It is even commented in the zend protocol code.    What this means is that if the character at logical pos 0 of each line is a "dot" then the test server tool does not properly handle it and the "extra dot" appears in the email received by the end user.

Comment: Worked brilliantly for me using WAMP 4 on Win10. Thanks Wesley!

Comment: How did you download it? I only see google ads in the download section.

Comment: to whoever doesn't find the download link go to here: https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/users-manual.html

Comment: This is what I call a good piece of software. 10 years later and it still works without any configuration needed at all, on Win 10.

Comment: Wish I knew about this years ago lol. Still works with Wamp, Win 10.

Comment: For those who want to download this without disabling adblock, here is the download link: https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/TestMailServerToolSetup.exe

Comment: @BenL localhost didn't work as smtp for me. I had to use the ip address 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 45):

Install [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) (download [sendmail.zip](http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip)).
Then configure  C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.example.com
smtp_port=465
auth_username=user@example.com
auth_password=your_password
```

The above will work against a email account.
And then configure  php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Now, restart Apache, and that is basically all you need to do.

Comment: +1 for turnkey solution. As an added resource for those who need a little more detail on the steps: http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: @gianjey Will this work with other accounts such as Hotmail or do you need a Gmail account registered to use this?

Comment: dang this method doesn't appear to be working anymore ... assuming i've gotten everything set up correctly

Comment: Hi @Banning, I was able to set this up without difficulty just now so it still works. Make sure you don't have two-step authentication configured on the GMail account. Anyway, this was a good guide - http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: I got message of successful email but mail not received in my inbox. any help?

Comment: I'm getting this message in Gmail: "Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account *******@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.:

Comment: Cant believe this worked first try!!! so incredible. Only part that messed me up is, if you are using gmail you need to put in your gmail user name and password so it can sign into the email client to SEND the email. NOTE: if you are going to do this, make a new gmail account since this increases the risk of security risk.

Comment: @DarkBee ok as you wish, But are you sure this answer is still relevant? It seems that it doesn't work anymore with google... Why to keep answer that is not working anymore?

Comment: That isn't relevant, you could still configure another SMTP server with this method, also there already numerous questions (and answers) on how to use google's SMTP server on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113637/how-to-use-phpmailer-after-30-may-2022-when-less-secure-app-is-no-longer-an-o)

Comment: @DarkBee yes that is correct. But could you maybe then update at least "smtp.GOOGLE.com"? Cos it is suggestive and I think not working...

Comment: There is no file C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.ini

Answer (score 5):

Using an open source program call [Send Mail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/), you can send via wamp rather easily actually.  I'm still setting it up, but here's a [great tutorial by jo jordan](http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2012/04/26/how-to-set-up-email-with-wamp/).  Takes less than 2 mins to setup.

Just tried it and it worked like a charm!  Once I uncommented the error log and found out that it was stalling on the pop3 authentication, I just removed that and it sent nicely.  Best of luck!

Comment: If you're using a Gmail account, you need to allow access for less secure apps. To do this, when you've done what is says in the tutorial linked in this answer and opened a PHP page with `mail`, you will receive an email from Google saying that a sign-in attempt was blocked. In that email, click on "Check activity", and in the page that opens, click on "Yes, it was me", then click on "Learn more", then click on "If 'Less secure app access' is off for your account", then click on "turn it back on", and then turn the switch on.

Comment: Also, you must specify a `from` header when calling `mail` in PHP. For example, you can do `mail("to@example.com", "Subject", "Content", "From: youremailaddress@gmail.com")` (it's the last parameter that's important).

Answer (score 2):

You need a SMTP server to send your mail. If you have one available which does not require SMTP authentification (maybe your ISP's?) just edit the 'SMTP' ([mail function]) setting in your php.ini file.

If this is no option because your SMTP server requires authentification you won't be able to use the internal mail() function and have to use some 3rd party class which supports smtp auth. e.g. http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

Answer (score 2):

I tried Test Mail Server Tool and while it worked great, you still need to open the email on some client.

I found **Papercut**:

https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP
(updated URL for 2021)

For configuration it's easy as Test Mail Server Tool (pratically zero-conf), and it also serves as an email client, with views for the **Message** (great for HTML emails), **Headers**, **Body** (to inspect the HTML) and **Raw** (full unparsed email).

It also has a **Sections** view, to split up the different media types found in the email.

It has a super clean and friendly UI, a good log viewer and gives you notifications when you receive an email.

I find it perfect, so I just wanted to give my 2c and maybe help someone.

Comment: Your link is now outdated. Here's the project in 2021 on Github: https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut-SMTP

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing and configure own SMTP server it is possible (easier) to use one's personal Gmail email and configure PHP/WAMP to use it and send email through it.

As of 2023 gmail does not support for personal users SMTP by default. So some earlier answers seems to be outdated. Now it seems to be necessary to enable `2-Way Authentication` first and then generated `App Password`.

So let's configure Google side first:

1. In your Gmail click your icon (in top right)->Manage your Google Account->Security->2-Step Verification
2. set it up (you will need to receive SMS).
3. Then when it is set up go to `2-Step Verification` again
4. At bottom there is `App password`->click it
5. - then Select app as "mail"
   - Select device as "Windows computer"
   - click "generate"
6. You will get 16 letters password which you will use later. So copy it.

Then you download `Sendmail with TLS support`. Basically it is app that takes text file with email address and subject and body. Then connects to SMTP server and send that.

You can download it from git hub:

https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main

I used this file to be precise:
[Sendmail_v33_TLS1_2.zip](https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main/blob/master/Sendmail_v33_TLS1_2.zip)

Unzip and configure `sendmail.ini` like following (don't forget to change `auth_username` and `auth_password` to your email and password):

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
; note this is useful to uncoment and peek if something doesnt work
; debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=yourEmail@gmail.com
auth_password= that-16-letters-password-you-got-from-Google-App-Password
```

To test sendmail is working create `test.txt` in sendmail folder. Like this (but **edit your receive email address**):

```
From: anything@example.com 
To: FillYourReceive@email.com 
Subject: Your Subject 
Your Body message
Your Body message second line
```

Then go to command line to `sendmail` folder and run it as:

```
sendmail.exe < test.txt
```

You shall receive email in few seconds. If not check `error.log` file or enable debug file in `sednmail.ini` and check `debug.log` file also.

When this works configure your `php.ini` (`wamp icon->PHP->php.ini [apache module]`

```
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from ="admin@wampserver.vbe"
sendmail_path = "c:/wamp64/bin/Sendmail_v33_TLS1_2/sendmail.exe -t"
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

Of course edit `sendmail_path` to where you have `sendmail.exe` and best copy it to `WAMP` folder.

Restart apache `wamp icon->Apache->Service Administration 'wampapache64'->Restart Service`

Then create web page in your document root like `test_mail.php` with following data. (Just remember to change `FillYOurReceiveEmail` :

```
<?php
echo "<br>sendmail_path:".strval(ini_get('sendmail_path'));

$from = "anything@anywhere.com";
$to = "FillYOurReceiveEmail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Your email subject";
$message = "Your email body message";
$headers = [ "From: $from" ];

$ret = mail( $to, $subject, $message, implode( '\r\n', $headers ) );
// OR - PHP 7.2.0 or greater
//mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
echo "<br>ret :".strval($ret);
?>
```

Then open in your browser page `localhost/test_mail.php`

You shall see something like:

```
sendmail_path:c:/wamp64/bin/Sendmail_v33_TLS1_2/sendmail.exe
ret :1
```

And you shall receive email to your filled email.

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail wasn't working for me so I used [msmtp 1.6.2 w32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msmtp/files/msmtp/1.6.2/) and most just followed the instructions at [DeveloperSide](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/using-gmail-and-msmtp-to-send-mail-from-php). Here is a quick rundown of the setup for posterity:

**Enabled IMAP** access under your Gmail account (the one msmtp is sending emails from)

**Enable access for less secure apps**. Log into your google account and go [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

**Edit `php.ini`**, find and change each setting below to reflect the following:

```
; These are commented out by prefixing a semicolon
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; Set these paths to where you put your msmtp files.
; I used backslashes in php.ini and it works fine.
; The example in the devside guide uses forwardslashes. 
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp64\msmtp\msmtp.exe -d -C C:\wamp64\msmtp\msmtprc.ini -t --read-envelope-from"

mail.log = "C:\wamp64\msmtp\maillog.txt"
```

**Create and edit the file `msmtprc.ini`** in the same directory as your `msmtp.exe` file as follows, replacing it with your own email and password:

```
# Default values for all accounts
defaults
tls_certcheck off
# I used forward slashes here and it works.
logfile C:/wamp64/msmtp/msmtplog.txt

account Gmail
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
tls on
from ReplaceWithYourEmail@gmail.com
user ReplaceWithYourEmail@gmail.com
password ReplaceWithYourPassword
account default : gmail
```

Comment: I couldn't install msmtp on windows. I can only find tar files.

Comment: Try the link in my answer and download `msmtp-1.6.2-w32.zip`
https://sourceforge.net/projects/msmtp/files/msmtp/1.6.2/

Answer (score 0):

I used Mercury/32 and Pegasus Mail to get the mail() functional.  It works great too as a mail server if you want an email address ending with your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first download Sendmail it really works fine and can send to multiple emails. You can download it from this Github address https://github.com/sendmail-tls1-2/main. Create a folder named sendmail under WAMP and extract it. Then open the file sendmail.ini for configuration as follow for Gmail

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=youremail@gmail.com
auth_password= here place the gmail generated app code not your email password
```

After this open your PHP.ini file used by Wamp in bin>php
under [mail function] section configure as follow

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = youemail@gmail.com
auth_username = youremail@gmail.com
auth_password = here place the same gmail generated app code not your email password
sendmail_path =  path\to\Ampps\sendmail\sendmail.exe
```

also check if this extension is in the php.ini file without a semi colon (using ctrl+f)
extension=php_openssl.dll
otherwise if not present just add it. Also check this file is present in the ext folder bin>php>php8..>ext (otherwise download it and paste it)
Don't forget you need also to create and use google app password
-Go to your Google Account.
Select Security.
Under "Signing in to Google," select 2-Step Verification.
At the bottom of the page, select App passwords.
Enter a name that helps you remember where you'll use the app password.
Select Generate. and that's it just paste the generated code in the php.ini and sendmail.ini and you are ready to go!