# Sending email from php on localhost

Tags: php, email

I am using XAMPP with Mercury and Thunderbird. When I send a message through Mercury, the message works fine and I receive the email on Thunderbird. When I try in a PHP script, it does not.

I am certain it has something to do with php but I haven't been able to find a solution as to why it is not sending.

I'm not getting any errors either and it's saying the message was sent.

mailtest.php:

```
$to = "patrick@localhost";
$subject = "hi";
$body="text".PHP_EOL;
$body.="this message was sent".PHP_EOL;
$headers = "From: postmaster@localhost";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "message sent!";
    } 
    else {
        echo "failed";
    }   
?>
```

php.ini:

```
[mail function]

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; I am on Windows 7 64bit
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
; sendmail_from = localhost
```

sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this sendmail program to use with an SMTP account like a gmail account. Here is the main project site http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ and here is a quick howto from another answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/11210090/209067

This is i what use for my local windows environment, i just can't find the full article tutorial where i learned about it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's my problem now, that I need to authorize my username and password.

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you! I have spent many frustrating hours trying to figure this out and now I got it!