# Task scheduler run successfully, but not sending email

Tags: php, email, scheduled-tasks

I develop a system using WampServer.

I try run the script using Task Scheduler. The program run successfully, but there is no output after all. Supposedly, an email is automatically send to me if there is no problem occur.

At the Program/Script under "Action Tab", I put .bat file that consist of this line :

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php-win.exe -f      
"C:\wamp\www\assetmanagementsystem\sendmail.php"
```

At the Start in, I put this line :

```
C:\wamp\www\assetmanagementsystem\
```

Is there any mistakes that I did here ? Please help me. I really need your help. Thank you.

P/s : I can get the email when I run it without using Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wamp on local windows machine won't send mail unless you have properly configured smtp for it.

You might refer to this:

[Configure WAMP server to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773288/configure-wamp-server-to-send-email)

It might or might not work, most ISP don't allow you to do so because of potential SPAM

Comment: I have configure the smtp for wamp, and I'm using sendmail to do so. I really need help on this.

Comment: @user2810332 assuming you have configured it correctly, I'd say it's ISP issues. Try to contact them and ask if they blocked local SMTP