# Sending and email from php file to my gmail account

Tags: php, email, wamp

I am trying to send an email through this php file, I am using WAMP server. I couldnt find the php.ini files to edit them, I am running these .php files on my locaclhost. The following is the code, kindly have a look, 
The error I am getting is `"Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 The address is not valid. in C:\wamp\www\Test\dbregister.php on line 69"`

```
<?php
// the following are for validating the inputs 

if (isset($_POST['name'])){
  if (ctype_alpha($_POST['name'])){
  $uname=$_POST['name'];}else{header('Location: register.php');};
}else{
  header('Location: register.php');
};

if (isset($_POST['pwd'])){
  $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
}else{
  header('Location: register.php');
};

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
  if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $email=$_POST['email'];}else{header('Location: register.php');};
}else{
  header('Location: register.php');
};

if (isset($_POST['sex'])){
  $sex=$_POST['sex'];
}else{
  header('Location: register.php');
};

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user"; // Table name 
@mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
@mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$gender=$_POST['sex'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(user_name, password, email)VALUES('$name', '$pwd',         '$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='first.php'>Back to main page</a>";
// everything till here works fine, I am able to see the data in the data base tables.
// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------
// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;  // the email address would be taken from the another webpage
// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";
// From
$header="From: sushwanth.n@gmail.com";
// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Test email \r\n";

// send email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);  // I am getting the error in this line.
//mail('sushwanth.n@gmail.com','Test Email','This is a test email.',"From:     sunnibaba1@gmail.com");
// I have used the above line too see if it works, but even that was showing and error
}

// if not found 
else {
echo "This email is already in use, If you are a registered user, clik below to login";
echo "<a href='login.php'>LOGIN</a>";
//echo " <form method="post" action="login.php"><input type="submit" name="login">    </form> ";
}
?>
```

Kindly let me know how to debug this and also if I need to include any other functions to get this working.

Comment: You'll need to have a mail server properly configured. See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773288/configure-wamp-server-to-send-email

Comment: Seriously, does `admin@tackemup` look even *remotely* like a valid email address to you? (and `sunnibaba1@gemail.com` for sure isn't one as well) ;-) And please, look at the PHP docs how to validate multiple attributes at once (you almost got it) and try to stay DRY! 8-) You should also switch to either `mysqli_*` or PDO as `mysql_*` functions are all deprecated.

Comment: @nietonfir : Sry about the spelling mistakes, I forgot make the changes of the email addresses before I post it, thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the SMTP server you're attempting to use requires authentication, something the native mail() command doesn't support. In this case, you'll need to use an external PHP class (ex. PHPMailer) and provide the SMTP server with valid credentials.

The file you need to configure is probably `sendmail.ini:`

make sure to include your email credentials and port