# PHP Errors - Total of four

Tags: php, html, email, post

This is my php code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Joerassic Park</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$to = "joerassicpark.ddns@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact For";
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$headers = "From: $email";
$sent = mail('joerassicpark.ddns@gmail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
if($sent){
print('<a href="contact.html">Thank you. Click here to return to site.</a>');
} else {
print "There was an issue with your contact form";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

And you can see my errors at joerassicpark.ddns.net/contact.php

Can Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the errors at least?

Comment: Please post your errors here so they are preserved with the question for future SO visitors.

Comment: You can view the errors at the url I posted

Comment: here they are:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 9
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0057 239744 {main}( ) ..\contact.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 10
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0057 239744 {main}( ) ..\contact.php:0

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 11
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0057 239744 {main}( ) ..\contact.php:0

( ! ) Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 13
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0057 239744 {main}( ) ..\contact.php:0
2 0.0245 241184 mail ( ) ..\contact.php:13

Comment: You should edit the question and paste that in. Also, you have a page named `contact.html` and also a page named `contact.php`? That's perfectly valid of course, but still.

Answer (score 2):

The errors are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 9
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 11
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 13
```

You are assuming that those keys exist in the POST array.

This code should fix 3 of 4 errors.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Joerassic Park</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$error = false;
$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : null;
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : null;
$message = isset($_POST["message"]) ? $_POST["message"] : null;

if(is_null($name) || is_null($email) || is_null($message)) $error = true;

if(!$error) {
    $to = "joerassicpark.ddns@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact For";
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail('joerassicpark.ddns@gmail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
}

if(!$error && $sent){
    print('<a href="contact.html">Thank you. Click here to return to site.</a>');
} else {
    print "There was an issue with your contact form";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

However your last error indicates that you do not have a mail server configured.

This has been answered in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773288/configure-wamp-server-to-send-email).

Comment: When submitting the forum I get this error as well Not Found

The requested URL /â€contact.phpâ€ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at joerassicpark.ddns.net Port 80

Comment: Sounds like the action attribute on your form is encoded wrong.

Comment: My forum looks like this
<form action=”contact.php” method=”post”>
     Name: <input type=”text” name=”name”>
     <br /><br />
     Email: <input type=”text” name=”email”>
     <br /><br />
     Message:
     <br />
     <textarea name=”message” rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
     <br /><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

Comment: Your quotation marks are not standard quotation marks, and therefore are being encoded strangely.