# PHPMailer using gmail going forward

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

As of May 30, 2022, Google disabled less secure app access options. I understand that setting a Google Account to allow less secure app access was the key for PHPMailer to send emails via Gmail. I took over the maintenance of a few websites where this PHPMailer/Gmail functionality was used for the 'Contact us' pages.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-an-app-password

Now that this option is gone - what are the alternative solutions that do not require re-engineering the core functionality for the existing Contact Us pages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHPMailer, after 30 May 2022 when "Less secure app" is no longer an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113637/how-to-use-phpmailer-after-30-may-2022-when-less-secure-app-is-no-longer-an-o)

Answer (score 1):

You first port of call should be to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps). You've not needed to to use less secure apps for the last 5 years, but lots of people didn't realise that so now there's a frantic rush. In short, [App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) are the easiest way to go as they don't require you to change your code at all, just update a password.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is to use use an apps password. This will require that you have 2fa enabled on your google account to create the apps password.

The second option is to use Xoauth2 to request authorization of the owner of the account. Then you can send an access token instead of the password.

There is a very good guide to how to set this up here [Using Gmail with XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2)

```
$mail->oauthUserEmail = "<your gmail address>@gmail.com";
$mail->oauthClientId = "237644427849-g8d0pnkd1jh3idcjdbopvkse2hvj0tdp.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$mail->oauthClientSecret = "mklHhrns6eF-qjwuiLpSB4DL";
$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "1/7Jt8_RHX86Pk09VTfQd4O_ZqKbmuV7HpMNz-rqJ4KdQMEudVrK5jSpoR30zcRFq6";
```

As long as this is a single user app you will not need to apply for verification.