# Sending gmail Using PHP for gmail

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Gmail Sending email using phpmailer not working,Less secure app access not available in gmail now,
what are the other methods to send emails in gmail using php ?

Comment: duplicate [After 30 May 2022 when "Less secure app" is no longer an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72113637/1841839)

Answer (score 0):

Correction.  Connecting to Googles SMTP server using the login and password for a google account not longer works after the removal of [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) on May 30, 2022.

The options are

1. Create an apps password and use that in place of the users actual password in your code. To create an apps password requires that the user have 2fa enabled on their account.  [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)
2. Use Xoauth2, to create an access token and pass that to your code [gmail_xoauth.phps](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps)
3. Third and final option would be to switch to using the Gmail api and authenticate the user.  Although if you have a google workspace account and can set up domain wide delegation using a service account would be easer.

Comment: Any other metods without app password

Comment: Yes option 2 Xoauth2, or option 3 gmail api.