# Why PHPMailer always having an issue?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I don't have issue about LESS SECURE APPS, because I already generated app password in google and pasted it in code. I just need help with this problem.

BTW, here’s the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'google-app-password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Customer Concern');
$mail->addAddress('mygmail@gmail.com');
$body = $_POST['message'];

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'test';

$mail->send();
```

Comment: Do you not have your own smtp server to send email?

Comment: @RiggsFolly sometimes it's better to use a reputable SMTP server in order to ensure e-mail delivery though

Comment: That's because you used a workaround for the deprecated  LESS SECURE APPS which probably has been deprecated as well. With Gmail the only way is to use OAuth2 authentication. This is for any mail library regardless the language and does not depend on PHPMailer but is a security policy enforced by google

Comment: Does this answers your question? [How to use PHPMailer, after 30 May 2022 when "Less secure app" is no longer an option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113637/how-to-use-phpmailer-after-30-may-2022-when-less-secure-app-is-no-longer-an-o)

Comment: @Justinas, I already set my app password and pasted the generated password but same issue 

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Sounds like your hosting provider may have started blocking outbound SMTP, which is very common. Read their docs, ask their support. It doesn't help that you have no error checking in your code.